# Orchard CMS Custom Module Not Loading

Tags: .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a custom Orchard module. It's not loading. I don't see it getting copied to App_Data\Dependencies or added to dependencies.xml.

It does show up in the Modules section of the Dashboard (where I have enabled it).

I don't see any errors in the Orchard error logs.

I have attached to the Orchard w3wp, but my dlls in the module's bin directory aren't getting loaded into the AppDoamin at all.

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

module.txt is below

```
Name: MyApp
Path: App
AntiForgery: disabled
Author: Me
Website: http://www.myapp.com
Version: 1.0.0
OrchardVersion: 1.6.0
Description: Module for Orchard
Category: Content
Dependencies:
```

This file is located in Modules\MyApp.

The dll in question is in Modules\MyApp\bin\MyApp.Web.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Orchard does some funny name matching on module names and it's components.

I have the following scenario:

Module.txt says name is MyApp

Module lives in Modules/MyApp

Website dll is MyApp.Web.dll. Class library is MyApp.dll.

Orchard decides to ignore my module.

If I change the Module.txt to say MyApp.Web, no change. If I ALSO change the virtual directory to be MyApp.Web, Orchard loads my module.

Comment: Am having the exact same issue here, crazy that nothing is logged and no exception is thrown... What do you mean by "Website dll" and "Class library dll" ? Is MyApp.Web.dll the dll for your hosting orchard website, or do MyApp.Web.dll and MyApp.dll both belong to your module ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have verified that the manifest is there and is valid, it's almost certainly not compiling. Try to open the solution from Visual Studio and build it from there. You should see build errors.

Comment: It compiles fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: Same result. No dll is added to the Dependencies directory and nothing relevant shows up in Dependencies.xml

Comment: Compare your manifest with one from a module that works. If that still fails, restart the app, attach a debugger configured to break on exceptions.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am experiencing the same problem: No build errors. Can't attach the debugger because the module never loads. The module appears in the Modules page of the dashboard. When I enable it, it says "Enabled" but  the module does not load. No error in the logs.

Comment: That the module doesn't load doesn't prevent you from attaching a debugger. When you do, does VS show breakpoints set in the module as hollow? How do you know it doesn't load?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue with a precompiled module, it's painful that nothing is logged